# Need little modification in Sql query I want check if data exist use that id else add row_number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables we will call them **FY19** and **Level1** so what I was doing that I was getting the value distinct value from **FY19** and then add **Lv1_LastDeptID** to it with Increment and then Insert into **Level1** the issue I am having now is that I want to check in **Level1** if the value exists in the table then use that id for that row but if not exist then add one column check every row

[image]

when i do `select * from FY19` Result

**FY19 Table Data**
[image]

When i run this Query will get result next Image

```
     SELECT Id,Description,   Ent,
          convert(varchar(40),

CASE WHEN  coalesce((SELECT max(Level1Id)
        FROM Level1),1) =-1 THEN 0 ELSE coalesce((SELECT max(Level1Id)
        FROM Level1),1)
  END    
           + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY user)) Lv1_LastDeptID
           FROM (SELECT Id,Description, Ent,
                        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Ent
                                           ORDER BY user) rn
                        FROM  FY19) t
           WHERE rn = 1 and  Ent != '-1'
```

when i execute this query i will get output like this

[image]

That's what i need its working correctly when Level1 table is empty

***Second Part**

Data in Level1 Table

[image]

But if we already have data in Level1 and and again we are running the same Partition Query it will give me this out put which is wrong because it is repeating ENT

[image]

So what i want when i excute the query when i have data in Level1 it should check if in Level1.Ent value equal to FY19.Ent value then it should take the Lv1_last_id from Level1 else it get the max(Level1Id) and Add it then again for new row it check the ENT else add

If we have new row in FY19 which is not in Level1 Table it should take the create the **Lv1_LastDeptID** for it but for **exist** data use the same  which are in Level1 table

```
  SELECT Id,Description,   Ent,
              convert(varchar(40),

    CASE WHEN  coalesce((SELECT max(Level1Id)
            FROM Level1),1) =-1 THEN 0 ELSE coalesce((SELECT max(Level1Id)
            FROM Level1),1)
      END    
               + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY user)) Lv1_LastDeptID
               FROM (SELECT Id,Description, Ent,
                            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Ent
                                               ORDER BY user) rn
                            FROM  FY19) t
               WHERE rn = 1 and  Ent != '-1'
```

Comment: Which tables in your code are Table one and Table two?  Your code users Level1 and FY19.  It's a little confusing

Comment: Level1 is TableTwo and FY19 is TableOne

Comment: You should use an IDENTITY column here if it is possible. Then you could just insert while left joining the target table eliminating no matches.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what you are trying to do as it's not clear.  For the sake of clarity, can you give an example of data from Level1 and FY19 and then desired output?  Then we can probably help you :)

Comment: I just modified the question hope this make more senses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will insert the Ent if not exists in the level table:

```
 WITH cteEnt(Ent,Description)
    AS
    (
      SELECT Ent,MAX(Description) FROM FY19 GROUP BY Ent
    ),
    cteNewEnt(Ent,Description,RowId)
    AS
    (
      SELECT e.Ent,e.Description, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY Ent) AS RowId
      FROM cteEnt e
      LEFT JOIN Level1 l
      ON l.Ent=e.Ent
      WHERE l.Ent IS NULL
    )
    SELECT CASE WHEN l.Lv1_Last_Id IS NOT NULL THEN l.Lv1_Last_Id ELSE ISNULL((SELECT MAX(Lv1_Last_Id) FROM Level1) ,0) + n.RowID, e.Ent, e.Description
    FROM cteEnt e
    LEFT JOIN cteNewEn n
    ON e.Ent=n.Ent
    LEFT JOIN Level1 l
    ON l.Ent=e.Ent;
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterHE I don't want to insert right now just want select data right now i tried to change this to select getting errors :(

Comment: This is perfect but i don't want to leave data in level1 when i run this query i want that data Id so i can replace it with id Example if there is l.ent = e.ent then the if equal to RowID for only that data